# UWP AppX Package creation failed when using .net Native

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, appx

I have a solution as follows:

- **App 1 Project** (Universal Windows App)
- **Portable Class Library Project** (Target Window 8, .NET 4.5, ASP.NET Core)
- **Style Class Library Project** (Universal Windows App)

I have build configurations debug & release configured identically (at least I hope so), except using .net native in release Configuration.

When creating a AppXBundle for **App 1** using the wizard in VS2017, it creates different results for the detected dependencies:

**Debug\Dependencies\x64:**

- Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx
- Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx

**Release\Dependencies\x64:**

- Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6.appx
- Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx

When installing the App-X Package created in debug configuration, using the generated **Add-AppDevPackage.ps1**, everything works fine. 
When doing the same thing with the App-X Package created in release configuration, I get the following error:

> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict
>   validation.
>   Windows cannot install package 93ede192-831a-47ed-b309-5c4901fd7ffc because package Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 was
>   provided but not used. This could be because package 93ede192-831a-47ed-b309-5c4901fd7ffc does not depend on
>   Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1. Only the packages that package 93ede192-831a-47ed-b309-5c4901fd7ffc depends on can be
>   installed.

**Assumption**: The **Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx** dependency should not be added during package creating, as .net native is selected in Release Configuration. When removing the file manually after package creation, installation works.

**Question**: Why is this dependency added in release configuration? Is this a bug?

**Note**: On Project **Style Class Library Project (Universal Windows App)**, there is no option to enable .NET native on the build tab, I think because of its output type (Class Library). Root cause?

Thanks

Comment: I'd think the problem here is related to the Portable Class Library Project as I've used Class Library (Universal Windows) Project in my project and it works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After cleaning up the solution and configuring all build configurations again, when compiling x64 or x86, the issue is now gone.

I couldn't say exactly which setting caused it, but if someone else is facing this one, I would recommend to check the following first:

- Build configuration of x64 & x86
- Assure .net native is selected on release configuration for alle UWP Apps
- Assure portable libraries are targeted correctly.
- Clean the solution & rebuild all configurations for debug & release
- Try again creating the store package

Thanks.